# Авторизация по токенам на ASP.NET web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-3

Добрый день. При стандартной авторизации по токенам в модели пользователя есть обязательное поле Email, а оно мне не надо. Соответственное при регистрации выдаёт ошибку, что поле Email не заполнено. Как можно сделать это поле необязательным?

Comment: Есть код модели?

Comment: @Sv__t, сначала я наследовал от класса IdentityUser и добавлял свои два поля (название и коллекцию связанных элементов) и всё работало с единственным минусом, что была емейл. Потом мне посоветовали наследовать от IUser, в котором было только два свойства необходимых для определения, и модель получилась такая: `public class ApplicationUser : IUser
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }`.

Comment: Но появилась ошибка при создании класса управления пользователями, что ApplicationUser нельзя использовать как TUser, тогда как при наследовании от IdentityUser всё было нормально.